# Airlink 101 causes BSODs on startup from DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL errors

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, bsod

I have an Airlink101 AWLH 3026 wirless adapter on an older desktop running Windows XP with 512 megabytes of ram (new install on an older box). Whenever I turn on the computer I keep getting these errors no matter what my ram configuration is. After about 3-5 reboots I normally can use the wireless just fine without the computer BSOD-ing.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Airlink101 AWLH 3026 w/Windows XP, d/l the Ralink RT25xx driver.

It solved my problem.

The thing that convinced me that it was a software problem: Puppy Linux worked perfectly.
P.L. is an excellent diagnostic tool, even if you don't want to use Linux.